# Connect to MySql database from my local system using phpMyadmin hosted on hostinger

Tags: mysql, remote-server

My MySql Database was hosted on hostinger server. I have tried to establish a connection with my MySql database using phpmyadmin which is on my local system. 
But it sends an error message as  'Cannot connect to MySql'.

I want to establish a connection to the MySql from PhpMyAdmin hosted on my local system.

Comment: Share your db connection code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant establish a connection to the MySql from PhpMyAdmin hosted in your  local system.the only way is to achieve that is to create an api for CRUD operations and host it in the same database server and consume the api

Answer (score 0):

> I want to establish a connection to the MySql from PhpMyAdmin hosted
>   on my local system

This option is only available for premium hosting on Hostinger, that mean you can't use Remote MySQL.

Comment: I have premium hosting on Hostinger